# Beginner Node.js routing upon on submit

Tags: node.js, express

Just starting to play with node, and having a little bit trouble on routing, I looked on the routing separation example but thought it was a little bit advance for my skill, so I did in the following way, would anyone advice on the following code

index.html

```
<div class="container" id="test-container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <span id="test-error"></span>
      <form id="test-input2">
        <input type="text" id="test"></input>
      </form>
</div>
```

ui.js

```
$('#test-input').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
socket.emit('route', null);
});
```

ui_backend.js

```
exports.listen = function(server){

    io = socketio.listen(server);
    io.set('log level', 2);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        route_testing(socket);
    });
}

function route_testing(socket){
    socket.on('route', function(req, res){
        res.render('test', function(err, html){

        });
    })
}
```

server.js

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/test.html');
});
```

Edit:

The problem is that I cannot get the routing to work.

Comment: can you clarify the problem?

Comment: @mihai, sorry, the main problem is that the routing does not work upon on submit

Comment: Are you trying to send them to `test.html` page after they successfully submit the form?

Comment: @Ali, Yes, that is correct, I am trying to test how routing works in node.js with express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

You setup a route in your `server.js`

```
app.get("/test", routes.page("test"));
```

In your `ui_backend.js`

```
module.exports = function (view) {
  return function (req, res) {
    res.render(view + ".html", {
      page: view
    });
  };
};
```

Just do `res.render()` is fine. sendfile is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code, but it didn't work, how did you setup the on submit event, did you use socket.emit and put the above code inside the exports.listen?

Comment: Oh this code I didn't include the socket.emit, but what you can do maybe setup another route for `app.post` or `app.put` and in your frontend js file when submit just send a post to the server and it should do what you want too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function route_testing(socket){
    socket.on('route', function(req, res){
        res.render('test', function(err, html){

        });
    })
}
```

with `socket.on(message,callback)` , there is no req,res arguments. You are mixing up express and socket.io api.

on a socket message you need to emit another socket message. `socket.emit(message)`

```
 socket.on('route', function(data){
            socket.emit(message,somedata);
        })
```

You basically have a server with 2 different protocols here, websockets and classic http.
The socket.io api is pretty clear: http://socket.io/ you cant make up a different api and expect it to work.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/test.html');
});
```

sends /views/test.html as an attachement. You dont want to do that,you want express to render some html template or page:

```
 app.get('/test', function(req, res){
        res.render('test');
    });
```

should work out of the box with a default express script.

**So when you want to query over http, use the express api.**

**when you want to send message through websockets,use socket.io api.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I am still confused, if I don't use socket, how does the backend know there is a on submit event, and can socket redirect webpage without using express?

Comment: In short, what function calls app.get via on click, I was under the impression that on submit event is handled using socket.io, can expression get called by the on submit event?

Comment: "how does the backend know there is a on submit event" only the browser knows that,but you dont allow the event completion with  `e.preventDefault()` ,socket.io cant redirect your webpage,like an ajax request cant redirect your webpage. Websockets are "like a persistant connection over TCP".

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to specify what app.get() I am calling in my $('#test-input').submit right? There could be 10 app.get, so how would I do that in frontend, I think I am missing a critical piece of syntax that enables the communication between app.get and $('#test-input').submit